# WinForms: How do I keep a panel from scrolling with the window content?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls

I have a navigation panel on the left hand side of my program and I'd like it to always stay where it is when scrolling the window content. Is there a way to do that?

I've thought about trying to do a get/set for its position but there's only a size property.

[image]

In the example above, the information in the top left is in a panel. Is there a way to keep it anchored there as the user scrolls down?

Comment: An image would probably help a lot.

Comment: use a table layout and some other container to scroll.

Comment: @DanWilson Added.

Answer (score 3):

You currently appear to have the Autoscroll option enabled on the Form.  Set that to false, then set up two panels, one for the toolbar/navigation and the other for the scrollable content.

Set the toolbar panel to be anchored to Top, Bottom, Left.  Set the content panel to be anchored to all four sides.  Set both panels to Autoscroll=True, then put the content in each panel.  When each panel gets too small to contain their contents they will scroll - independently - which will in most cases mean that the toolbar/navigation will stay put while the content will be scrollable.  If the toolbar panel also gets too small then it will be scrollable too:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I meant anchor the toolbar panel to the top, bottom and LEFT.  Edited above.

Comment: How did you go, did this answer help?  If so, please mark it as the answer so others can benefit.